# Accessing nested YAML/JSON objects with Handlebars

Tags: json, handlebars.js, yaml

I have YAML similar to the below

```
props:
  MY_NAME:
    value: '2px'
    meta:
      css: 'padding'
```

and I'm trying to access values via Handlebars similar to below:

```
{
    "props": [
        {{#each props as |prop|}}
        {
            "name": "{{prop.name}}",
            "value": "{{prop.value}}",
            "meta": {
                "css": "{{prop.meta.css}}"
            }
        },
        {{/each}}
    ]
}
```

(I'm creating a new JSON document from the YAML)

How do I access the values underneath "meta"? `{{prop.meta.css}}` does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties under meta are referenced as you said {{props.meta.css}}

If you have doubts about your data you can print them with the following code :

```
{{#each this}}
        Key: {{@key}} 
        Value = {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

For example with your props (to see if you have a meta property):

```
{{#each props}}
        Key: {{@key}} 
        Value = {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

And if you have a meta property check the nested meta properties :

```
{{#each props.meta}}
        Key: {{@key}} 
        Value = {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

If you can see props.meta it can be that your props.meta is an array then you have to either iterate over your array with {{each}} or use the direct access notation {{props.meta.0}} to get the first item of your array.